# How to create a data object of the sort required to run occupancy models for the spOccupancy CRAN package?

Tags: r, dataframe, list, matrix, formatting

I am trying to run an occupancy model using the spOccupancy package in R. I have rows for each site, and columns which have occurrences, site covariates, survey covariates, and coordinates. However the package requires the data to be formatted oddly, so I can’t just import it from a whole CSV file. Instead it requires it to be a list object with four components. The first component is supposed to be a 3 dimensional array of species detection/ non-detection data, the second component is a data frame of environmental variables, the third component is a list, with a different list per covariate (and those lists are data frames), and the final component is a matrix of the x & y values. I don’t even know how to begin formatting my table, with all my data, into this format, so any help would be greatly appreciated.